# Form a power series from a list

Tags: series-expansion

Say I have a list

```
L = {0,1,2,4,6}
```

how can I form a power series with coefficients in L

```
x + 2x^2 + 4x^3 + 6x^4
```

?

Comment: (I'm sure this is a dupe, but I can't find the original.) Try `Expand[FromDigits[Reverse[{0, 1, 2, 4, 6}], x]]`

Comment: also `L. x^Range[0, Length[L] - 1]`?

Comment: Or `SeriesData[x, 0, L, 0, Length@L, 1]` if someone wants a `Series`...

Comment: @MichaelE2 - `SeriesData[x, 0, L, 0, Length@L, 1] // Normal` for polynomial

Comment: If I further want to define a function `f[t_] := p[Exp[2 Pi t]]` how can I do it? When I do it and evaluate `f[0]` I don't get a value, rather I get an expansion

Comment: @Bernoulli - don't ask new questions in comments. Also, when asking the new question you must include the definition of `p` for anyone to understand why you are getting an expansion.

Comment: @BobHanlon I didn't wanted a polynomial. I wanted an alternative to the polynomials in first two comments.